Run npm script without npx for a scope NPM package CLI
When I run npm run generate npm script, got error:
> @svgr/cli --out-dir ./src/components --typescript -- ./src/assets

/cli does not exist
npm error Lifecycle script `generate` failed with error:
npm error Error: command failed

But build, lint npm script can be executed correctly. I remember if the CLI packages are installed locally, we don't need to use npx like npx tsc.
As you can see, I have already installed the @svgr/cli package.
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "generate": "@svgr/cli --out-dir ./src/components --typescript -- ./src/assets",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "vite-plugin-dts": "^4.3.0",
  "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
  "@svgr/cli": "^8.1.0",
  "@types/node": "^22.10.1",
  "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
  "eslint": "^9.15.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
  "globals": "^15.12.0",
  "typescript": "~5.6.2",
  "typescript-eslint": "^8.15.0",
  "vite": "^6.0.1"
},


Node: v18.20.3
Npm: 10.7.0


npm install @svgr/cli --save-dev

Have a look at the usage docs of this package. The CLI command is not @svgr/cli but just svgr ...

Pretty obvious that a command like @svgr/cli won't work because / is a path separator and that command would be interpreted as "run the executable cli in the subfolder @svgr"

Typo, feel free to close

Run:
npm install @svgr/cli --save-dev
Add to config:
"scripts": {
   "generate": "svgr --out-dir ../src/components --typescript ./src/assets"
}

